# building for iOS, but linking in object file built for macOS, file '…/Release-iphoneos/libRNVectorIcons.a' for architecture armv7

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, linker-errors

When compiling a release archive for the "Generic iOS device" on Xcode 10,
after having upgraded tons of libraries (incl. react-native, native-base),
I'm encountering the following error. (It currently works in the simulator.)

```
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

This also happened to the `bugsnag-react-native` library, wihch I removed, now it's this.

My environment:

```
    "native-base": "^2.11.0",
        "react-native-vector-icons": { "version": "6.1.0", } // from package-lock.json
```

Xcode: Version 10.1 (10B61)

---

Are the ar archives in question published by the library developers or compiled by Xcode? Have they forgotten to compile in code for another architecture or has my xcode forgotten to do so?

Any suggestions or ideas would be appreciated,
Thank you!

Comment: Was this originally compiled on Xcode 9* or earlier? If so, you'll need to change the build settings form "new" to "legacy".  The fact that it pops up during the archive phase makes me suspect this.

Comment: It was, but it's now fixed and builds well for simulator! Archive compiling with the legacy build system now fails with different errors.

Comment: @galva, I am getting same issue. Can you please share your solution?

Comment: This was a while ago. I don't maintain this product nor do I use react native any more. Sorry.